# InDither deprecated in android N

Tags: android, bitmap

As the title implies the `inDither` field in `BitmapFactory.Options` is now deprecated. Android doc says "This field was deprecated in API level 24. As of N, this is ignored." Does anyone know why it has been deprecated and is there a alternative for this?

Answer (score 1):

seems it is too late to answer...

if you use **canvas.drawBitmap**, you may try:

```
Paint().apply {
            isDither = false
            isFilterBitmap = false
            isAntiAlias = false
        }
```

and for **ImageView**, setLayerPaint seems not suitable, you may create a **BitmapDrawable** like:

```
BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap).apply {
            setAntiAlias(false)
            isFilterBitmap = false
        }
```

1. [Android: Disabling anti-aliasing for pixel art](http://www.41post.com/4241/programming/android-disabling-anti-aliasing-for-pixel-art) (blog)
2. [Disable anti-aliasing on Android Imageview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46028774/disable-anti-aliasing-on-android-imageview)  (StackOverflow question)