# Disable anti-aliasing on Android Imageview

Tags: android, imageview

I'm showing 96x96 pixel art sprites in imageviews and can't get it to display without applying anti-aliasing (or at least some form of interpolation, if it isn't anti-aliasing), which ruins the sharp edge of the sprites.

How can this be done? I've tried the following methods I've picked up from around the internet, but none work.

**METHOD ONE**

creating an xml resource file with a bitmap, and setting the anti-alias flag to false. Didn't work at all

**METHOD TWO**

creating a bitmap object from the resource, and setting the anti-alias flag to false. Didn't work at all.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dryad_back_large);
    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    drawable.setAntiAlias(false);
    playerMonsterImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

**METHOD THREE**
Using sprites which are large enough so that they will never need to be scaled down, only up (512x512 worked for me)

So this third method WORKS, but it seems really ham-fisted, and I was hoping there was a better way of going about this.

Maybe there's something other than anti-aliasing going on here that I've missed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are multiple things that may be scaling your image with anti-aliasing.

One is `BitmapFactory`. For example, if you have a `drawable-mdpi` resource and the current resource configuration is `xhdpi`, it will scale at decode time. You can provide options to avoid this, but the easiest way around it is to put these resources in `drawable-nodpi`.

The canvas also scales the image with bilinear sampling by default. To avoid that, use a `Paint` with `.setFilterBitmap(false)` when drawing to the `Canvas`. One way to do that is by using a custom `Drawable` which wraps the underlying `.draw()` call with a `DrawFilter` modifying the desired paint flags.

```java
public class AliasingDrawableWrapper extends DrawableWrapper {
    private static final DrawFilter DRAW_FILTER =
        new PaintFlagsDrawFilter(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG, 0);

    public AliasingDrawableWrapper(Drawable wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        DrawFilter oldDrawFilter = canvas.getDrawFilter();
        canvas.setDrawFilter(DRAW_FILTER);
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.setDrawFilter(oldDrawFilter);
    }
}
```

```java
imageView.setDrawable(new AliasingDrawableWrapper(getDrawable(R.drawable.bitmap)));
```

Comment: Ah yes, putting the images in drawable-nodpi worked like a charm, thanks so much!

Comment: On closer inspection, the images are actually still blurry. What version of the DrawableWrapper class is being used? None of them seem to have an onDraw method.

Comment: `android.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper`. I meant to write `draw()` not `onDraw()`, fixing.

Comment: Thanks, works well. Any chance something like this could work on anything below API 23? With an older version of the library or something?

Comment: @Dportology Copy `DrawableWrapper`, since the support library versions aren't part of the public API (unfortunately). But it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yup worked well. I just copied the v7 library and there don't seem to be any issues. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

In **"METHOD TWO"**, set the filter of the `Drawable` to `false` with

```
drawable.setFilterBitmap(false);
```

instead of using the `setAntialias` method you mention.

Comment: After a lot of search finally works with this Big Thanks dude ;)
i set `drawable.setAntiAlias(false);` but has no effect, after setting `drawable.setFilterBitmap(false);` it works.